# How to get the values of the final layer of a DNN using KERAS?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

I've just began using Keras to train a simple DNN and I'm struggling on setting my custom Loss Function, here's the code of the Model:

```
X_train = train_dataframe.to_numpy()[:, 0:4]
Y_train = train_dataframe.to_numpy()[:, 4]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_shape=(4,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(Y_train.shape[0], activation='linear', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.02)))

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred): 

    mse_loss = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true,np.ones((450, 4)) * y_pred)
                                              
    return mse_loss + y_pred

model.compile("adam", custom_loss(X_train, model.layers[2].output), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=1)
```

I will briefly explain. I got a training set of 450 samples and 4 features for each one as input and a (450,1)  numerical vector pared to the training set.

Now, what I would like to obtain is a sort of LASSO regression by applying the activity regularizer on the last layer and then building my custom loss function where I put a MSE between y_true (which is the input) y_pred which is not the output but a simple multiplication of the output layer values with a (450,4) matrix (for semplicity is filled with ones).

My problem is that I got this error when I run the script:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 450 for 'mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: 
[450,4], [?,450].
```

And maybe it is because I'm not extracting well the values of the output layer doing `model.layers[2].output`. So How can I do this properly using Keras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making 2 crucial mistakes:

1. Don't pass arguments for the loss in .compile keras is smart enough for that:

   ```
    model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
   ```
2. If you want apply some multiplication to the last layer then create a custom layer for that, don't do it inside the loss function; the loss function's job is only to find out how far the predicted value are from real one

Comment: Thank you for the tips, so the custom layer should be put after the output layer? And How could I retrieve the values of the output layer in order to use it in the custom layer?